# Check if field is assigned a non-null value during static initialization using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class A
{
    public Wrapper<int> wrapper0 = new Wrapper<int>();
}

public class B
{
    public Wrapper<int> wrapper1;
    public Wrapper<int> wrapper2 = null;
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is this:

```
1. typeof(A).GetField("wrapper0").IsStaticallyInitialized -> returns true
2. typeof(B).GetField("wrapper1").IsStaticallyInitialized -> returns false
3. typeof(B).GetField("wrapper2").IsStaticallyInitialized -> returns false
```

Case number 1 returns `true` because field `wrapper` is getting initialized in static context with `new Wrapper<int>()`. Meanwhile, cases 2 and 3 return `false` because we do not initialize those fields or set them to null.

**Important thing to say is that I don't have an instance of either A or B, I just need to get information whether a field is statically initialized or not.**

Is is possible to implement `IsStaticallyInitialized`?

Answer (score 0):

Initialization statements like these are actually moved into the constructor of the class by the compiler. You need to instantiate a class in order for the initializers to be executed and then you can check the values.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I am using Unity game engine and creating instances of some classes is out of the question. So, I guess this cannot be easily solved...